# Is there any benefit in using await with an async method without intermediate work?

Tags: c#, async-await

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) uses the below example:

```
async Task<int> AccessTheWebAsync()
{ 
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    Task<string> getStringTask = client.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com");

    DoIndependentWork();

    string urlContents = await getStringTask;

    return urlContents.Length;
}
```

So the `GetStringAsync` method will basicallly promise to return a Task of type string at some point in the future, but by the time `DoIndependentWork` is called, `getString` hasn't been `awaited` yet so it can continue to do other work until this happens.

But the documentation then says

> If AccessTheWebAsync doesn't have any work that it can do between
>   calling GetStringAsync and awaiting its completion, you can simplify
>   your code by calling and awaiting in the following single statement.

```
string urlContents = await client.GetStringAsync();
```

Is there any benefit to doing this at all if you're just going to await something straight away? Or is it just so you're preparing in advance to use asynchrony as your applications develops?

Comment: I guess that they are trying to explain async methods here and the possibility to await them. This is not a matter of benefit or not, just a possibility. In other words: This will not receive any performance gain, but is also bad practice if implemented like this. Await exists, and can be great when used correctly, but this is a simplified example, not a correct case.

Comment: Well if you didn't `await client.GetStringAsync();` you'd presumably have to call `client.GetString()` synchronously, which would turn your async `AccessTheWebAsync()` into a synchronous method (assuming there was no other use of `await` in it).

Comment: "doing this", please explain exactly what **this** you're referring to here, it's a bit hard to understand exactly what you're asking about.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I meant the code snippet directly above. Calling await on an asynchronous method directly. `string urlContents = await client.GetStringAsync();`

Comment: OK, then the reason I asked was because your question, that statement, sounded like "Is there any point in doing X if you're just going to do X". What is the alternative? You have to await it at *some* point. FYI, the way you have structured the method in the topmost example is exactly how I would do it, do as much as needed before having to wait for the resources.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I guess it would be better to say: Is there any point using/creating an asynchronous method, instead of a synchronous method, if you're just going to await the result from the async method immediately?

Comment: Well, if you can return the asynchronous task directly, then you should do so, let the caller await, but you want to return the length, and if you want to return a task you would have to let the caller determine the length. Basically, if you intend to process the result of the asynchronous operation before returning, then you should await, but there often very little point in `return await ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main advantage is that `await <some-operation-that-does-I/O>` doesn't tie up a thread in a wait, improving resource utilization. A thread will only be commissioned when the I/O completes. You can have many more outstanding I/O requests on a system than you can have waiting threads. Stephen Cleary has an [article on this](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) that explains it more eloquently than I can.

Answer (score 1):

The designer of an awaitable async method, thought that chances are high that somewhere during execution of the method he would have to wait for something to complete.

Instead of a busy wait, he gives you the possibility to do "something else" until you either need the result of the method or have nothing to do anymore.

It might be that you have no "something else" to do but your caller might or his caller. Even if no one has something else to do, using the async give the operator the opportunity to start something else, for instance minimize the window. We call this "keep the UI responsive".

So the answer is: yes, even if you have nothing to do and just await anyAsyncFunction(), it is meaningful to be an async function yourself whenever you call any other async function.

Comment: What if there is no UI, meaning, what if your code is running on a webserver, or in a Windows service?

Comment: Especially on Web servers, whenever the web server has to wait idly for another process to finish, like the result of a database query, or like writing to a file, it would be nice if the web server didn't have to wait idly for the other process to finish, but would be free for another web request.