# If I'm going to use the result from await immediately, do I get any benefit from async?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

Consider the code in this example:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

In several places they have code that looks like this:

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Product>();
}
return product;
```

The way I see it, if there is no independent code following the await, then there is little benefit to using async.  (I know that there are many API's that are *AsAsync() only, so in those cases I don't have a choice.)

Or am I missing something?  Is there a benefit for going all async, all the time?

Comment: The purpose is to not block caller on long running operations,it's not about dependent or independent code

Comment: Let's say, hypothetically, that `response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Product>();` takes 1 minute to complete.  Would you prefer your application be in a state of pause just waiting on this to complete?  Or would it be preferable to have your code come back to that line after the operation is complete?

Comment: When you are running to do IO operations or Network calls, you are freeing your thread to do other work, when the outbound work is done a hardware interupt signals so another free thread can continue to do the remainder of the work

Comment: Duplicate of following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36762679/is-there-any-benefit-in-using-await-with-an-async-method-without-intermediate-wo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is benefit as we are not blocking caller on the operation that we are doing which is not the case  for sync calls.

Think of it was called in windows form application as synchrounous call then on a button click suppose, then the app would be unresponsive and user wouldn't be able to do any operation until the call to Web API method complete s either with success or failure which we don't want nowadays in many cases I.e keep the application responsive for better UX.

The basic purpose is to simplify the old way of using background worker class to do long running operations or I/O bound operations. The asynchronous execution will cause not to block the caller code and resume from where it left when the result is returned back from the operation.

So in the above case calling a Web API method involves network latency and it could take more than normal time and if we are not calling it asynchronously we have blocked the calling code or thread until the result is returned.

### Update:

To clarify Calling async method without await wouldnt block but your control would  flow through  and you won't be able to access the result while await would keep that context, without await  you will have to wait  for it to complete and block it like `Async().Result` which ofcoruse means calling async method synchronously.

Hope it helps

Comment: But in this particular example, since there is no code after the WebAPI call (indeed the next thing that happens is we return the result of the WebAPI call) what is the benefit?

Comment: Keeping the application responsive

Comment: @AlfredBr check out the comment I posted on the main question.  It does not matter if there is code after it or not, the outer method cannot "complete" until the `ReadAsAsync` call completes.  So your entire app will be stuck waiting for that to finish unless you use async/await.  Imagine your UI being frozen until this completes.  Imagine all other processes taking longer because resources are being wasted just waiting and not doing anything

Comment: That does not seem to be the case.  If I do NOT use await, then the code continues to run.  If I use await, I stop until the WebAPI call returns and I get the result.

Comment: @AlfredBr You have that backwards.  When you use `await` it creates a state machine and returns when the task is complete, if you dont use await you are just locking your app up, and its just stuck waiting doing nothing

Comment: Calling async method without await wouldnt block but your control would  flow through  and you won't be able to access the result while await would keep that context, without await  you will have to wait  for it to complete and block it like Async().Result which ofcoruse means calling async method synchonosly

Comment: @maccettura if we are not calling .Result on it then it wouldn't stuck the app it's kind of fire and forget then

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Yes, you are correct.  However the OP's code shows that the object they ultimately return (`product `) is being set by the result of the async call.  So the code would not compile without the await keyword, because then the result of the call would be `Task` and `product` is likely not of type `Task<T>`